# Assertj extract and contains doesn't match

Tags: assertj

I made a simple test :

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setFirstName("Stéphane");
p.setLastName("Traumat");

assertThat(p)
.extracting("firstName", "lastName")
.contains(tuple("Stéphane", "Traumat"));
```

And I get a strange result :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
<["Stéphane", "Traumat"]>
to contain:
<[("Stéphane", "Traumat")]>
but could not find:
<[("Stéphane", "Traumat")]>
```

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a tuple, the result of `extracting` in your case is a simple array, please also have a look at the javadoc for [`extracting`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#extracting-java.lang.String...-), it contains an example showing how to use it.